# Validation expression in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

How to disallow use of double quotes `"` in a textbox

Comment: @Oded, what? you can't read minds? pfff

Comment: the appropriate response to the effort people put in to answering your question would be for you to accept an answer that helps solve your problem.  That's what this community is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

Since you can never control what users do the client you might as well just check it on the server, so you would probably use code something like:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Contains("\""))
{
Response.Write("Dey aint no way I'm letting you type that!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `RegularExpressionValidator` and set the `ValidationExpression='^[^\"]*$'`, that will allow anything, including empty, other than `"`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want users to be able to type quotes in the textbox in the first place, consider using a [FilteredTextBox](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) from the AJAX Control Toolkit.

Comment: this only works if the user doesn't disable javascript. It's not a validation solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`RegularExpressionValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx) for your page input validation. The .NET validation controls will verify your users' input on both sides, the client-side, and the server-side which is important if the user has disabled JavaScript. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx) might also help you to implement the validation of your ASP.NET server controls.

**Please don't do this just with JavaScript or AJAX**. Always perform a server-side input validation! Especially if you are writing the users' input back into a database ([SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified if you're using webforms or MVC, so I'm gonna throw a couple things a'cha.

First off, here's the Regex you'll use in either situation.  `^[^\"]*$`

First for WebForms

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" id="Regex1" controltovalidate="TextBox1" validationexpression="^[^\"]*$" errormessage="Nope!" />
<!-- This will give you client AND server side validation capabilities-->
```

To ensure you're valid on the **SERVER SIDE**, you add this to your form submit method

```
If Page.IsValid Then
    ''# submit the form
Else
    ''# your form was not entered properly.  
    ''# Even if the user disables Javascript, we're gonna catch them here
End If
```

In MVC you should definitely use [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) on your ViewModel
**NOTE: DataAnnotations can also be use for [WebForms](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html) if you're planning on doing a lot of repeat <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>**

```
''# fix SO code coloring
''# this is in the view model
<RegularExpression("^[^\"]*$", ErrorMessage:="Nope")>
Public Property TextBox1 As String ''# don't actually call it TextBox1 of course
```

And in your controller "Post" action, you wanna add the following

```
If ModelState.IsValid Then
    ''# submit the form
Else
    ''# your form was not entered properly.  
    ''# Even if the user disables Javascript, we're gonna catch them here
End If
```

Comment: Crap, just tested my Regex, and it's not working. The principals are all there, and the concept is right... lemme work on the regex after I get some food in me.

Comment: fixed.  I was trying to eliminate `""` instead of just `"`